# kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException when starting my application

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

## Output

kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

    at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity.getNumLabels(FdActivity.kt:448)

      at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity.onCameraFrame(FdActivity.kt:219)

## Code

```
protected val numLabels: Int  
    protected get() = labelList!!.size //this is where the nullpointer is detected
protected val numLabelsG: Int
    protected get() = labelListG!!.size


    try {
        labelListG = loadLabelListG()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
    try {
        labelList = loadLabelList() //this is where the nullpointer is detected
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
```

***The problem***

I converted my java file into a kotlin file and managed to solve some errors but somehow I encountered this problem when starting my app.
Why do I always get a kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException?

Edit

## Code

```
private var labelList: List<String>? = null
private var labelListG: List<String>? = null //the variables are declared right after the the class activity
```

Comment: the `!!` operator causes a `KotlinNullPointerException` to be thrown if the target variable contains `null`, which means that `labelList` is `null`. Where do you initialise it?

Comment: I initialised my two variables within the class activity just right after it @user2340612  these are the two variables .

Answer (score 3):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

because operator (!!) converts any value to a non-null type and throws an exception if the value is null.

you are trying to get `labelList!!.size` even `labelList` is null, thats why you are getting NPE

check value is null or not

```
//example
val b: String? = null
val l = b?.length ?: -1 //here ?: is Elvis Operator
```

if the expression to the left of ?: is not null, the elvis operator returns it, otherwise it returns the expression to the right. Note that the right-hand side expression is evaluated only if the left-hand side is null.

> In Kotlin, the type system distinguishes between references that can
>   hold null (nullable references) and those that can not (non-null
>   references). For example, a regular variable of type String can not
>   hold null:

```
var a: String = "abc"
a = null // compilation error
```

> To allow nulls, we can declare a variable as nullable string, written
>   String?:

```
var b: String? = "abc"
b = null // ok
print(b)
```